# how to define a sample avatar in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, avatar

I want to show last comments in my side bar in wordpress, if the person who has sent a comment has gavatar it will be shown but if he does not have , in my template there is a default picture like below : 
[image]

how can I cusomize this picture ? and show my  favorite avatar ?

Answer (score 0):

The get_avatar() function has a $default parameter, allowing you to set a custom url to an image you specify

```
<?php echo get_avatar( $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar

Answer (score 0):

Add into function.php

```
if(!function_exists('custom_avatar')){
function custom_avatar($avatar_defaults){
$new_default_icon = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/custom/images/new-avatar.png';
$avatar_defaults[$new_default_icon] = 'My Custom Avatar';
return $avatar_defaults;
    }
add_filter('avatar_defaults','custom_avatar');
}
```